# Why am I getting a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" error after compiling my program?

Tags: java, file

[image]
[image]

I have uploaded two screen shot which are related to my java. When I try to compile a java file, it compiles the java file correctly and creates the .class file successfully, but when I try to run the compiled file it gives an error message. I have attached two screen shots which are related to this problem. Please help me.

Here is the stack trace that I get trying to run with `java Test` command:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Test : Unsupp
orted major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessControll.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Test. Program will exit.
```

and with `java Test.java`command:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessControll.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: Test.java. Program will exit.
```

Comment: This is a Java programming question and does not appear to be specific to Ubuntu. As such it is off-topic. Please consider posting it to StackOverflow.com.

Comment: Please copy, paste and format your output, I cannot read that.

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues. The first, as mentioned by @davidfmatheson, is that you have compiled the program under one version of Java and are trying to run it in another. You either need to recompile in Java 6, or run it in Java 7.

The second issue is with your command line. When you compile, you need to pass `javac` the filename, *including* the extension, but when you run it, `java` takes the name without the extension:

```
> javac Test.java
> java Test
```

This is the source of the `NoClassDefFound` error.

Answer (score 1):

The version number of 51.0 means that you've compiled with JDK 1.7.  Check `which javac` from your command-line.  Then you try to run it using `java Test` with a Java that's evidently version 1.6.  Find out where your JDK 1.6 is located, ensure that the `javac` in 1.6 comes first on the `PATH`, and recompile your `Test` class.